# Build a Twilio Autopilot bot IVR that answers phone and follows instructions

Tags: twilio

I am trying to build a bot that can answer a call. The caller would say a phrase like "Press 1" and the bot would play digits 1.

If the caller said Press 2, the bot would respond by playing digits 2, and so on.

Any insight would be helpful. Thank you

Lu

Comment: What do you mean "play digits 1" and "play digits 2"?

Comment: The ‘digits’ attribute lets you play DTMF tones during a call.

Comment: Just to confirm--`sendDigits`? https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits ?

Comment: Hi Lizzie,Yes so basically the twilio number will receive a call. The caller will say a phrase that includes a number to press. So for example the caller will say Hi Press 1. I would need the twilio autopilot to  play DTMF tone 1 in response. Is this possible with the twilio autopilot system?

Comment: yes it is very possible! see answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Welcome to StackOverflow!

This [Node.js quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/quickstart/node) has the first few steps you'd need to make a voice bot with Autopilot.

First, you'd buy a Twilio phone number [here](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/search).
Then, you'd configure that number with the URL from your Twilio Autopilot bot. That number would be found under `Channels` on the lefthand side of your Autopilot bot. [image]
Click *Programmable Voice* and copy this URL [image] and then paste it under *Voice & Fax* for when a call comes in next to *webhook*:
[image]

Next, you could then make a task for each possible phrase the user could say. If the phrase is "press 1", you could redirect to a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/manage) that uses `sendDigits` to play DTMF tones when the call is answered. The Twilio Autopilot task could include this JSON:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "redirect": {
                  "uri": "https://YOUR-TWILIO-FUNCTION-URL.twil.io/actions",
                  "method": "POST"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then your Function code could be

```
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;
const response = new VoiceResponse();
const dial = response.dial();
dial.number({
    sendDigits: 'wwww1928'
}, 'replace-with-number-to-dial');
console.log(response.toString());
```

Alternatively, you could have one Autopilot task and then use a conditional in the Twilio Function to check which number the user said. That would include code similar to this:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;
    const response = new VoiceResponse();
    const dial = response.dial();
    let responseObject = {};
    let memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);
    console.log(memory.twilio.collected_data);
     let num = memory.twilio.collected_data.your_collect_function_name.answers.your_question_name.answer;
    console.log(num); //collected data from memory
    if(num == 0 || num == "zero") {
        dial.number({
            sendDigits: '0'
        }, 'replace-with-number-to-dial');
        console.log(response.toString());
    }
};
```

Let me know if this helps at all!